# How can I generate a fix string for a specific name which is associated for that name only

Tags: php, jquery

I want to generate fix string for name which is associated for that name only.

For example:

my string: `test`
generated string: `elephant`

If I write test again then it must generate string elephant in any browser or in any machine

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: have you heard about constant ? try using constant - <?php
define("TEST", "ELEPHENT");
echo TEST;
?>

Comment: Yes, the string will be dynamic which will enter by user in textbox and based on that we need to generate a unique string for that name

Comment: @Rahul2790 how about the name itself?

Comment: yes
if i write Rahul2790 then string will be different and if i write rahul2790 then also string will be defferent

Comment: You really aren't clear on what you need. There's an infinite number of ways to transform a string to another string in a consistent manner.

Comment: I want to do it with jquery

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jQuery is the right answer, but you could use it for handling XHRs to get the transformed string from a PHP back-end.

It sounds like you want deterministic hashing of strings to dictionary words. Using a single word as your result is far more likely to result in a collision; use 3 or more. Give your PHP back-end access to a large dictionary: a simple, non-profane word list, which *must not change*, in a file or a database table with a 0-based index. Pass it the input string to hash using something like sha256. Take equal length slices of the hash string and with each slice, look up one word by converting the slice's hexadecimal to an integer, add the integer to the previous index if it's not the first, modulo (`%`) the integer by the length of the dictionary to get an index and add the word at that index to your result.

Comment: Is there any example or library for the same?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can do it. First, find a word list, it doesn't have to be big whilst testing, 256 words is good because 1 byte has 256 possible values. `sha1($input, true)` will return a 20-byte, binary string. Use a loop with 3 steps to take 6-byte substrings, loop through each substring 1 byte at a time to add and modulo the result to get an index. Add the word from that index to your output. When you've got it working, switch to a list with 65,536 words, and loop through each substring 2 bytes at a time to get the index.

Comment: Use `unpack('C', $byte)` to convert a single byte to an int, and `unpack('n', $bytes)` to convert two bytes.